# Past continuous for length of time

Tags: past-tense

Someone asks

How long did you work there?

1. I worked there for two years
2. I was working there for two years

Do you agree that 2 is natural as long as our intention is to emphasize the length of time?

Comment: Please don't use that word natural. It can be inaccurate.  It's not about length. I'm working for two hours today. PAST: I was working for two hours today. It emphasizes the activity  versus a description of past, finished thing. This question has been answered here many times.

Comment: Look here point 4  https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-continuous-tense/#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20use%20the%20past%20continuous%20tense%20to%20emphasize,all%20day%2Fnight

Comment: Yes, sure, BUT: the main difference between I was working and I worked is NOT the adverbs of time in point 4. The difference is in the meaning of the tenses. All those time expressions can go with simple past as well...

Comment: On average we choose simple I just want to know if continuous when I add 2 yours is fine and sounds good?

Comment: The continuous version is *very* unlikely unless you're going to continue talking about *other* things you did at the same time (or immediately *after* that time, but still in the past). As a rule, though, don't over complicate things. Just use simple past unless you *know* you need a continuous form. In most cases, even if it's *possible* to use past continuous, it won't be noticed if you use simple past. But there are ***many*** contexts where it will be noticed if you use continuous incorrectly!

Comment: You don't really agree with point 4 on that site ,then?

Comment: I'm not gonna say I disagree with your link. But note #4 says *You **can** also use the past continuous tense...* It doesn't say you ***must***. So don't use it, is my advice.

Comment: I mean it would be incorrect o say "I was working in May" if I don't folloe it up but adding " I was working all May" makes is right. That's why I asked

Comment: I know I don't have to I just want to know if you think that point 4 is valid or not? Don't you think it may be fine with some contex like " Wow you don't look too good I know I was working there for 2 years non stop I had no time to  care about myslef"?

Comment: it was *always* "all right" until you switched to past continuous! And looking again, I ***do*** take issue with your link. Their example *The players were training all year for this match* may be syntactically valid, but in almost all contexts it would be better to say *The players **trained** all year for this match*. You're not doing yourself any favours by actually *trying* to use past continuous!

Comment: So it is possible but not very common it's better to stay with simple. Does the same applies to for instance "I was working all day" simple is better here, too?

Comment: Hi! To improve your questions and get better answers, check out [these guidelines](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If the question is "is it okay to say ___," then try to say more about why you suspect it might *not* be okay. That way the answer can be more than "yes" or "no" and can address the "why."

Comment: And remember that comments aren't really part of the question. If you have extra information to add, make sure you edit the question itself.

Comment: You can add time expressions to just about anything. Please be careful with those who tell you not to use a tense. It depends on what you want to say. Hey Bob, so, how long were you working there? Bob: I was working there for two years!

Comment: Look at the way "Someone" asked "How long did you work there?" and reply using the same tense: "I worked there for 2 years." Asking "How long were you working there" suggests a more detailed discussion involving other events that happened.

Comment: *"Hey Bob, so, how long were you working there?"* Just because the *speaker* used an unnecessarily complex verb form is no reason why you should "endorse" it by doing the same. Bob's most natural reply is probably almost always *"I **worked** there for two years!"* As ever, I maintain that learners *consistently* overuse complex verb forms!

Comment: I know that please answer one question " I was working all day". Here again there is no need for continuous but it is acceptable right ?

Comment: I counted 5 comments that said *working* is acceptable.

Comment: Progressive doesn't necessarily emphasise length. You might say "I didn't learn a lot when I was there. I was working there for two years, which isn't long at all." You use progressive when you are talking (or thinking) about something happening while you were working there, either implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: but you can also say  I only worked there for 2 years can't you ?